# Trying to validate TextFormField with null input but its not working and popping some weird error in Flutter [P.S: Still a learner]

Tags: validation, dart, flutter, flutter-layout

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:splash_screen/login_signup/signuppage.dart';

class LoginPage extends StatefulWidget {
  static String tag = 'login-page';
  @override
  _LoginPageState createState() => _LoginPageState();
}

class _LoginPageState extends State<LoginPage> {
  final formKey = new GlobalKey<FormState>();

  String _email;
  String _password;

  void validateAndSave() {
      final form = formKey.currentState;
      if(form.validate()){
        print('Login Successful');
      }
      else{
        print('Login Failed!');
      }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
        resizeToAvoidBottomPadding: false,
        body: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              child: Stack(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Container(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(16.0, 90.0, 0.0, 0.0),
                    child: Text('Log In',
                        style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 40.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
                  ),
                  Container(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(125.0, 60.0, 0.0, 0.0),
                    child: Text('.',
                        style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 80.0,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                            color: Colors.green)),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
            Container(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 35.0, left: 20.0, right: 20.0),
                key: formKey,
                child: Column(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    TextFormField(
                        decoration: InputDecoration(
                            labelText: 'EMAIL',
                            labelStyle: TextStyle(
                                fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                color: Colors.grey),
                            focusedBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                                borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.green))),
                        validator: (value) => value.isEmpty
                            ? 'Please Enter a Email Address' : 
                            ),
                    SizedBox(height: 20.0),
                    TextFormField(
                        decoration: InputDecoration(
                            labelText: 'PASSWORD',
                            labelStyle: TextStyle(
                                fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                color: Colors.grey),
                            focusedBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                                borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.green))),
                        obscureText: true,
                        validator: (value) =>
                            value.isEmpty ? 'Password cannot be empty!' : null),
                    SizedBox(height: 5.0),
                    Container(
                      alignment: Alignment(1.0, 0.0),
                      padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 15.0, left: 20.0),
                      child: InkWell(
                        child: Text(
                          'Forgot Password',
                          style: TextStyle(
                              color: Colors.green,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                              fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
                              decoration: TextDecoration.underline),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(height: 40.0),
                    Container(
                      height: 40.0,
                      child: Material(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
                        shadowColor: Colors.greenAccent,
                        color: Colors.green,
                        elevation: 7.0,
                        child: GestureDetector(
                          onTap: () {
                            validateAndSave();
                          },
                          child: Center(
                            child: Text(
                              'LOGIN',
                              style: TextStyle(
                                  color: Colors.white,
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                  fontFamily: 'Montserrat'),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(height: 20.0),
                    Container(
                      height: 40.0,
                      color: Colors.transparent,
                      child: Container(
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            border: Border.all(
                                color: Colors.black,
                                style: BorderStyle.solid,
                                width: 1.0),
                            color: Colors.transparent,
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0)),
                        child: Row(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                          children: <Widget>[
                            // Center(
                            //   child:
                            //       ImageIcon(AssetImage('facebook.png')),
                            // ),
                            SizedBox(width: 10.0),
                            Center(
                              child: Text('Log in with facebook',
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                      fontFamily: 'Montserrat')),
                            )
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    )
                  ],
                )),
            SizedBox(height: 15.0),
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                Text(
                  'Dont have an account?',
                  style: TextStyle(fontFamily: 'Montserrat'),
                ),
                SizedBox(width: 5.0),
                InkWell(
                  onTap: () {
                    // Navigator.of(context).pushNamed('/signup');
                    Navigator.push(context,
                        MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SignupPage()));
                  },
                  child: Text(
                    'Register',
                    style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.green,
                        fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                        decoration: TextDecoration.underline),
                  ),
                )
              ],
            )
          ],
        ));
  }
}
```

So, I was trying to implement TextField validator in my login page. And I sort of implemented it, don't know what's going wrong with it but it shows gesture exception where I am not able to find any solution for it, even tried searching on the internet for understanding what that error means.

the exception I see on terminal looks like this

https://i.stack.imgur.com/EqFyk.jpg

The image shows the terminal output for gesture exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You havn't used Form as an Parent to TextFormField.
Wrap your Container in Form Widget.

```
Form(
key: formKey,
child: Container(
     padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 35.0, left: 20.0, right: 20.0),
.....
```

Comment: Thank you so much yes it started working. Still understanding some concepts.